# Unit Test: How to mock document.getElementsByClassName() in react?

Tags: reactjs, testing, dom, jestjs, enzyme

I have this component i did with create-react-app and i want to test following function with jest/enzyme.

(The function handleArrow triggers when the up/down arrows are pressed in an input)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './styles.scss';
import Results from '../Results';
import ContextualSearchService from '../../services/contextualSearch';

class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchInput: '',
      onInput: false,
      searchResults: [],
      searchService: new ContextualSearchService(),
      filteredSearch: [],
      fetching: false,
    };
    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
    this.sendSearch = this.sendSearch.bind(this);
    this.selectSuggestion = this.selectSuggestion.bind(this);
    this.handleFocus = this.handleFocus.bind(this);
    this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur.bind(this);
    this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this);
    this.handleArrow = this.handleArrow.bind(this);
  }

  handleSearch(e) {
    this.setState({
      searchInput: e.target.value,
      fetching: true,
    });
  }

  handleFocus() {
    this.setState({onInput: true});
  }

  handleKeyDown(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 38 || e.keyCode === 40) {
      this.handleArrow(e.keyCode);
    }
    this.handleFocus();
    if (e.key === 'Enter' && this.state.searchInput !== '') {
      const selected = document
        .getElementsByClassName('search__dropdown-option--selected')[0];
      if (selected) {
        this.setState({searchInput: selected.innerText}, () =>{
          this.sendSearch();
          this.handleBlur();
        });
      } else {
        this.sendSearch();
        this.handleBlur();
      }
    }
  }

  handleArrow(e) {
    const list = document.getElementsByClassName('search__dropdown')[0];
    const len = document
      .getElementsByClassName('search__dropdown-option').length;
    const arr = Array.from(document
      .getElementsByClassName('search__dropdown-option'));
    let selected = document
      .getElementsByClassName('search__dropdown-option--selected')[0];
    let index = arr.indexOf(selected);
    let next = null;

    if (index === -1 && list) {
      index = 0;
      selected = list.getElementsByClassName('search__dropdown-option')[0];
      selected.classList.add('search__dropdown-option--selected');
    } else if (e === 40 && list) {
      if (selected) {
        index++;
        selected.classList.remove('search__dropdown-option--selected');
        next = list.getElementsByClassName('search__dropdown-option')[index];
        if (next !== undefined && index <= len) {
          selected = next;
        } else {
          index = 0;
          selected = list.getElementsByClassName('search__dropdown-option')[0];
          selected.classList.add('search__dropdown-option--selected');
        }
        selected.classList.add('search__dropdown-option--selected');
      }
    } else if (e === 38 && list) {
      if (selected) {
        index--;
        selected.classList.remove('search__dropdown-option--selected');
        next = list.getElementsByClassName('search__dropdown-option')[index];
        if (next !== undefined && index >= 0) {
          selected = next;
        } else {
          index = len - 1;
          selected = list
            .getElementsByClassName('search__dropdown-option')[index];
          selected.classList.add('search__dropdown-option--selected');
        }
        selected.classList.add('search__dropdown-option--selected');
      }
    }
  }

  handleBlur() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({onInput: false});
    }, 100);
  }


  sendSearch() {
    this.state.searchService.getSearch(this.state.searchInput)
      .then((res)=>{
        this.setState({
          searchResults: res,
          fetching: false,
        });
      });
  }

  selectSuggestion(term) {
    this.setState({
      searchInput: term,
    }, () => {
      this.sendSearch();
    });
  }

  render() {
    const activeInput = this.state.onInput;
    const term = this.state.searchInput;
    if (this.state.fetching && term !== '') {
      this.state.searchService.getSuggestions(term)
        .then((res)=>{
          this.setState({
            filteredSearch: res,
            fetching: false,
          });
        });
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="search-row">
          <div className="search-wrapper container">
            <div className="search">
              <input type="text"
                className="search__input"
                value={this.state.searchInput}
                onChange={this.handleSearch}
                onFocus={this.handleFocus}
                onBlur={this.handleBlur}
                onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
                placeholder="Buscar..."/>
              {
                (term !== '' && activeInput &&
                  this.state.filteredSearch.length > 0) &&
                <div className="search__dropdown">
                  {
                    this.state.filteredSearch.map((obj, i)=>{
                      return (
                        <div key={i}
                          onClick={()=>this.selectSuggestion(obj)}
                          className="search__dropdown-option">{obj}
                        </div>
                      );
                    })
                  }
                </div>
              }
            </div>
            <button className="btn btn-search" onClick={this.sendSearch}>
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                width="24"
                height="24"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16
                5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59
                4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5
                11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z">
                </path>
              </svg>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        {
          this.state.searchResults.length > 0 &&
          <Results results={this.state.searchResults}></Results>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```

So far, i have tried this:

```
it('should work', () => {
  const dropdown = global.document.createElement('div');
  const option = global.document.createElement('div');
  const selected = global.document.createElement('div');
  dropdown.classList.add('search__dropdown');
  option.classList.add('search__dropdown-option');
  selected.classList.add('search__dropdown-option--selected');
  global.document.body.appendChild(dropdown);
  dropdown.appendChild(option);
  dropdown.appendChild(selected);

  jest.useFakeTimers();
  const comp = mount(<Search/>);
  comp.setState({
    fetching: true,
    searchInput: 'the',
    onInput: true,
    searchResults: data,
    filteredSearch: filtered,
  });
  comp.setState({searchInput: 'the'});
  comp.find('.search__input').simulate('keydown', {key: 'Enter'});
  comp.find('.search__dropdown-option').at(0).simulate('click');
  jest.runAllTimers();
  comp.unmount();
});
```

When i run the test the "index" variable is always -1 (thing that i don't understand because i just appended the needed element in the DOM).

It appears that the problem comes from the line `let index = arr.indexOf(selected);`

Is there another better way to handle classes and DOM elements like this in react?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed Bruce Smith advice and i ended simplifying the code and just using state:

```
class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchInput: '',
      onInput: false,
      searchResults: [],
      searchService: new ContextualSearchService(),
      filteredSearch: [],
      fetching: false,
      dropdownIndex: 0,
    };
    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
    this.sendSearch = this.sendSearch.bind(this);
    this.selectSuggestion = this.selectSuggestion.bind(this);
    this.handleFocus = this.handleFocus.bind(this);
    this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur.bind(this);
    this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this);
    this.handleArrow = this.handleArrow.bind(this);
    this.getDropdownClass = this.getDropdownClass.bind(this);
  }

  handleSearch(e) {
    this.setState({
      searchInput: e.target.value,
      fetching: true,
    });
  }

  handleFocus() {
    this.setState({onInput: true});
  }

  handleKeyDown(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 38 || e.keyCode === 40) {
      this.handleArrow(e.keyCode);
    }
    this.handleFocus();
    if (e.key === 'Enter' && this.state.searchInput !== '') {
      const selected = this.state.filteredSearch[this.state.dropdownIndex];
      if (selected) {
        this.setState({searchInput: selected}, () =>{
          this.sendSearch();
          this.handleBlur();
        });
      } else {
        this.sendSearch();
        this.handleBlur();
      }
    }
  }

  handleArrow(e) {
    const len = this.state.filteredSearch.length;

    if (e === 40) {
      this.setState({
        dropdownIndex: this.state.dropdownIndex+1,
      }, () => {
        if (this.state.dropdownIndex >= len) {
          this.setState({dropdownIndex: 0});
        }
      });
    }
    if (e === 38) {
      this.setState({
        dropdownIndex: this.state.dropdownIndex-1,
      }, () => {
        if (this.state.dropdownIndex <= 0) {
          this.setState({dropdownIndex: len-1});
        }
      });
    }
  }

  handleBlur() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({onInput: false});
    }, 100);
  }

  sendSearch() {
    this.state.searchService.getSearch(this.state.searchInput)
      .then((res)=>{
        this.setState({
          searchResults: res,
          fetching: false,
        });
      });
  }

  selectSuggestion(term) {
    this.setState({
      searchInput: term,
    }, () => {
      this.sendSearch();
    });
  }

  getDropdownClass(index) {
    if (index === this.state.dropdownIndex) {
      return 'search__dropdown-option search__dropdown-option--selected';
    } else {
      return 'search__dropdown-option';
    }
  }

  render() {
    const activeInput = this.state.onInput;
    const term = this.state.searchInput;
    if (this.state.fetching && term !== '') {
      this.state.searchService.getSuggestions(term)
        .then((res)=>{
          this.setState({
            filteredSearch: res,
            fetching: false,
          });
        });
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="search-row">
          <div className="search-wrapper container">
            <div className="search">
              <input type="text"
                className="search__input"
                value={this.state.searchInput}
                onChange={this.handleSearch}
                onFocus={this.handleFocus}
                onBlur={this.handleBlur}
                onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
                placeholder="Buscar..."/>
              {
                (term !== '' && activeInput &&
                  this.state.filteredSearch.length > 0) &&
                <div className="search__dropdown">
                  {
                    this.state.filteredSearch.map((obj, i)=>{
                      return (
                        <div key={i}
                          onClick={()=>this.selectSuggestion(obj)}
                          className={this.getDropdownClass(i)}>{obj}
                        </div>
                      );
                    })
                  }
                </div>
              }
            </div>
            <button className="btn btn-search" onClick={this.sendSearch}>
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                width="24"
                height="24"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16
                5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59
                4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5
                11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z">
                </path>
              </svg>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        {
          this.state.searchResults.length > 0 &&
          <Results results={this.state.searchResults}></Results>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason your using javascript DOM selectors for your component as opposed to doing this in a React component? This functionality can be done directly in a React component if you're not familiar. Here's taking your existing code and adding selectedIndex in state so you can set that in state and have the proper element with the added modifier class...

```
export default class Search extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            fetching: false,
            filteredSearch: [],
            onInput: false,
            searchInputValue: '',
            searchResults: [],
            searchService: new ContextualSearchService(),
            selectedIndex: null,
            selectedValue: null,
        };
        this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
        this.sendSearch = this.sendSearch.bind(this);
        this.selectSuggestion = this.selectSuggestion.bind(this);
        this.handleFocus = this.handleFocus.bind(this);
        this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur.bind(this);
        this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this);
        this.handleArrow = this.handleArrow.bind(this);
    }

    handleSearch(e) {
        this.setState({
            searchInput: e.target.value,
            fetching: true,
        });
    }

    handleFocus() {
        this.setState({onInput: true});
    }

    handleKeyDown(e) {
        const {selectedIndex, selectedValue} = this.state;
        const {keyCode} = e;

        if (keyCode === 38 || keyCode === 40) {
          this.handleArrow(keyCode);
        }

        this.handleFocus();

        if (e.key === 'Enter' && this.state.searchInput !== '') {
            if (selectedIndex > 0) {
                this.setState({searchInput: selectedValue}, () => {
                    this.sendSearch();
                    this.handleBlur();
                });
            } else {
                this.sendSearch();
                this.handleBlur();
            }
        }
    }

    handleArrow(keyCode) {
        const {selectedIndex, filteredSearch} = this.state;
        const filteredSearchLength = filteredSearch.length;
        let newSelectedIndex;

        if (keyCode === 38) {
            newSelectedIndex = (this.state.selectedIndex === 0)
                ? filteredSearchLength - 1
                : selectedIndex - 1;
        } else {
            newSelectedIndex = (selectedIndex + 1 === filteredSearchLength)
                ? 0
                : selectedIndex + 1;
        }

        this.setState({selectedIndex: newSelectedIndex});
    }

    handleBlur() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({onInput: false});
        }, 100);
    }

    sendSearch() {
        this.state.searchService.getSearch(this.state.searchInput)
            .then((res)=>{
                this.setState({
                    searchResults: res,
                    fetching: false,
                });
            });
    }

    selectSuggestion(term, i) {
        this.setState({
            searchInput: term,
            selectedIndex: i,
        }, () => {
            this.sendSearch();
        });
    }

    render() {
        const activeInput = this.state.onInput;
        const term = this.state.searchInput;
        if (this.state.fetching && term !== '') {
            this.state.searchService.getSuggestions(term)
                .then((res) => { 
                    this.setState({
                        filteredSearch: res,
                        fetching: false,
                    });
                });
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="search-row">
                    <div className="search-wrapper container">
                        <div className="search">
                            <input type="text"
                                className="search__input"
                                value={this.state.searchInput}
                                onChange={this.handleSearch}
                                onFocus={this.handleFocus}
                                onBlur={this.handleBlur}
                                onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
                                placeholder="Buscar..."/>
                            {
                                (term !== '' && activeInput &&
                                    this.state.filteredSearch.length > 0) &&
                                <div className="search__dropdown">
                                    {
                                        this.state.filteredSearch.map((obj, i) => {
                                            // Or you could use that classnames library I suggested here
                                            const className = (i === this.state.selectedIndex)
                                                ? 'search__dropdown-option'
                                                : 'search__dropdown-option search__dropdown-option--selected';

                                            return (
                                                <div key={i}
                                                    onClick={() => this.selectSuggestion(obj, i)}
                                                    className={className}>{obj}
                                                </div>
                                            );
                                        })
                                    }
                                </div>
                            }
                        </div>
                        <button className="btn btn-search" onClick={this.sendSearch}>
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                width="24"
                                height="24"
                                viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16
                                5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59
                                4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5
                                11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z">
                                </path>
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {
                    this.state.searchResults.length > 0 &&
                    <Results results={this.state.searchResults}></Results>
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

However, I would recommend breaking your component up some so it isn't long and adding a new component like this for instance for your dropdown options...

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';

class DropDownOptions extends Component {
    getClass() {
        return classnames({
            'dropdown-option': true,
            'drowndown-option--selected': this.props.selected
        });
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.props.onClick(this.props.value, this.props.selectedIndex)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={this.getClass()} onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.children}</div>
        );
    }
}
```

classnames is a node module to modify classes in elements, but you could build your own functionality there like I did in the code I modified.

One last thing since you were asking about testing in the original question, here's a little example on how you could test this with jest. I'd highly recommend going through some of the docs on jest and also check out enzyme.

```
import Search from '../Search';

describe('Search', () => {
    it('should render', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Search />);

        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

    it('should set selected dropdown', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Search />);
        const wrapperInstance = wrapper.instance();

        wrapper.setState({
            filteredSearch: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
            selectedIndex: 0,
        });
        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
        wrapperInstance.handleArrow(38);
        expect(wrapperInstance.state.selectedIndex).toBe(2);
        wrapperInstance.handleArrow(40);
        expect(wrapperInstance.state.selectedIndex).toBe(0)
    });
});
```

Comment: I used javascript DOM selectors because the method "handleArrow" is triggered when moving the arrows in the input, the dropdown itself is never touched, but i see where you're coming from, i'll try that and update the post, thanks.

Comment: It's a little difficult to see the big picture here as well. Could you edit your question to include the full component as well in your code block?

Comment: OK... I modified your code a little and put it in the edited answer above, but in the interest of time, I didn't get into how to break it apart. I'm mainly showing you how you can do this with state instead. This should simplify your unit testing considerably and removes the problem of trying to figure out where your index is.